# How to multiply quad_form output with square of a variable in CVXPY?

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to learn how to multiply `power(lmbd,2)` with `quad_form(z,A)` in my objective. I think this part produces the error message `Error is Problem does not follow DCP rules.`

```py
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.power(lmbd,2) * cp.quad_form(z, A)) - lmbd*cp.matmul(z.T, s))

constraint = [cp.sum(z) == 1, z >= 0]
```

Belows are my expressions:

```py
lmbd = cp.Variable()

A = np.random.rand(d, d)  
A = np.dot(A.transpose(),A)

z = cp.Variable(d)

s = np.random.randn(d)
```

Look forward your help. Thank you!

Comment: What is lmbd ? Why is it a variable ? It doesn't have any constraint. And what do you mean by multiply? Matrix or elementwise multiplication?

Comment: lmbd  is stated as a self-weighted parameter in paper I am working on. Only constraint is constraint = [cp.sum(z) == 1, z >= 0] . Objective I am trying to solve  is lmbd^2*z.T*A*z - lmbd*z.T*s.  I am new to this topics. That is all I know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I also need to find lmbd optimal value. The equation tries to find optimal min values of z and lmbd.

Comment: Your problem is not convex threfore cvxopt can't solve it. You'd have to find another solver such as gurobi or try to transform the problem mathematically.